# UI with python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql

How to create a UI which shows the data in a presentable format and keeps getting updated dynamically?

MySQL queries needs to be executed automatically to take data from a database. Currently this task has to be done manually by executing each query.

So how to make a UI and how to link it with MySQL queries that can be made to run automatically ?

Comment: first, you need to decide type of application. a desktop, web or mobile app?

Comment: thats called phpmyadmin, you dont need python.